# How does &x vary from x if x is a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, ampersand

So...I have the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
const char *s="hello, world";
cout<<&s[7]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

and it prints "world"...however I don't understand why this:

```
int main(void)
{
const char *s="hello, world";
cout<<s[7]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

only will print "w" (all I changed is got rid of the ampersand), but I thought that was the "address of" operator...which makes me wonder why you need it and what it's function is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`s[7]` is the character `'w'`, so `&s[7]` becomes the **address** of the character `'w'`. And when you pass *an address* of `char*` type to `cout`, it prints all characters starting from the character to the null character which is end of the string i.e it continues to print characters from `'w'` onward till it finds `\0` . That is how `world` gets printed.

Its like this,

```
const char *s="hello, world";
const char  *pchar = &s[7]; //initialize pchar with the address of `w`
cout<< pchar <<endl; //prints all chars till it finds `\0`
```

Output:

```
world
```

However, if you want to print the address of `s[7]`, i.e value of `&s[7]`, then you've to do this:

```
cout << ((void*)&s[7]) << endl; //it prints the address of s[7]
```

Now we pass an address of `void*` type, so `cout` wouldn't be able to infer what it used to infer with `char*` type address. `void*` hides all information regarding *the content* of the address. So `cout` simply prints *the address* itself. After all, that is what it gets at the most.

Online demonstration : http://www.ideone.com/BMhFy

Answer (score 4):

Your title doesn't match your question... at all.

Since `s` is a pointer to char (aka C-style string), `s[7]` is a char.  Since `s[7]` is a char, `&s[7]` is a pointer to char (aka C-style string).

Answer (score 0):

s[7] is a character. (You can index into pointers to an array as if it was just the name of the array).

&s[7] is a pointer to the character at index 7. it's type is char*, so the stream inserter treats it like a char*.